# Fetching access_token from Linkedin via Retrofit POST using urlencoded

Tags: android, retrofit, linkedin-api

I could not find any solution about fetching access_token from Linkedin api. Here is my codes:

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
public interface RetrofitServiceforLinkedin {

        @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST ("uas/oauth2/accessToken")
        Call<LinkedinResponse> getDataLinkedinAccessTokenviaRest(
                  @Field ("code") String code);   
}
```

LinkedinResponse.class

```
public class LinkedinResponse {
    private DataLinkedinAccessToken data;
    public DataLinkedinAccessToken getData() {
            return data;
    }
    public void setData(DataLinkedinAccessToken data) {
            this.data = data;
    }
}
```

DataLinkedinAccessToken.class

```
public class DataLinkedinAccessToken {
    String access_token;
    String expires_in;
    public String getAccess_token() {
            return access_token;
    }
    public String getExpires_in() {
            return expires_in;
    }

}
```

in Fragment class i basically getting AccessToken by using RetrofitService.

```
  private void getLinkedinAccessToken(String authorization_code) {
            Log.i("ACCESS", authorization_code);
            Call<LinkedinResponse> call = RestClientLinkedin.getRetrofitService().getDataLinkedinAccessTokenviaRest(authorization_code);//
            Log.i("ACCESS", authorization_code + "  : NO PROBLEM");
            call.enqueue(new Callback<LinkedinResponse>() {
                    @Override//
                    public void onResponse(Call<LinkedinResponse> call, Response<LinkedinResponse> response) {
                            Log.i("ACCESSenönce", response.body() + "  : is response null?");
                            if (response.body() != null) {                                        dataLinkedinAccessToken.add(response.body().getData());
                                    Log.i("ACCESSönce", response.body().getData().toString());
                                    access_tokenLinkedin = response.body().getData().getAccess_token();
                                    Log.i("ACCESSson", access_tokenLinkedin);
//logtime
            }
                    }
```

so access_tokenLinkedin is coming null? I could not find any solution about this.

Comment: did you hit api on POSTMAN for check its giving response or not?

Comment: i could not understand you,sorry i am new at android and services...

Comment: but in LOGs i have saw that the response.toString is {protocol=h2, code=400, message=, url=https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken}

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Linkedin api provides access_token by exchange it via autorization_code. so first thing that should done is exchange them by using 
UrlEncoded html POST as below.

```
   public interface RetrofitServiceforLinkedin {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST ("uas/oauth2/accessToken")
    Call<LinkedinResponse> getDataLinkedinAccessTokenviaRest(
              @Field ("grant_type") String grant_type,
              @Field ("code") String code,
              @Field ("redirect_uri") String redirect_uri,
              @Field ("client_id") String client_id,
              @Field ("client_secret") String client_secret
    );
```

}